# Rust, FFI, and lifetime for string transmutation

Tags: rust, ffi, lifetime

I'm working in an FFI library and have encountered this pattern quite a few times that I don't know how to handle idiomatically.

```
impl CanVoidStar for str {
    fn as_cvoid_ptr(&self) -> *const c_void {
        let string = CString::new(self).unwrap(); 
        unsafe {
            return mem::transmute(string.as_ptr());
        }
    }
}
```

My intent was to create a `const *void` pointer to a piece of memory that I can hand off to a C function. The problem that here is that `string` goes out of scope and thus I get undefined behavior in the `unsafe` block.

Is there a way I can keep `string` allocated on the heap until whatever it is that is using the return value done with it? Further, is there a idiomatic way to handle this or do I need to redesign my algorithms?

Comment: http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong method on `CString`, and [`CString::into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_raw) is what you want.  Even better, it needs no `unsafe` code until you want to free the memory again.

While `CString::as_ptr()` returns a pointer into the string, `CString::into_raw()` passes the ownership of the memory into the raw pointer; this is intended for exactly your use case:

```
trait CanVoidStar {
    fn as_cvoid_ptr(&self) -> *const c_void;
}

impl CanVoidStar for str {
   fn as_cvoid_ptr(&self) -> *const c_void {
        let string = CString::new(self).unwrap();
        string.into_raw() as *const c_void
    }
}
```

As the documentation says, if you ever want to free it, you'll need to reconstruct the `CString` using [`CString::from_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_raw) and then have it dropped as usual.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I needed and works as expected. Thanks Chris.